# Split operation for each row in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this query -

```
LOAD CSV from "file:/C:/1m/movies1.csv" AS rows 
FIELDTERMINATOR ';' unwind rows as row
foreach (r in row|
SPLIT(r[3],"|") as genre
merge (c:Genres { name: genre }) 
merge (m:Movies { MovieID: row[1] }) 
MERGE (m)-[:HAS_GENRE]->(c))
```

the rows are like this -

```
1;Toy Story (1995);Animation|Children's|Comedy
2;Jumanji (1995);Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3;Grumpier Old Men (1995);Comedy|Romance
4;Waiting to Exhale (1995);Comedy|Drama
```

So the third element of each row has multiple values that I want to unwind with '|' delimiter. But I get the **error**-

```
Invalid input 'P': expected 't/T' or 'e/E' (line 4, column 2 (offset: 108))
"SPLIT(r[3],"|") as genre"
```

How do I split for the third item in each row and add merge them to a node?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, FOREACH stuff can be accomplished with UNWIND.

```
LOAD CSV from "file:/C:/1m/movies1.csv" AS rows FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
MERGE (movie:Movie {MovieID:rows[0]})
SET movie.name = rows[1]
WITH movie, SPLIT(rows[2], "|") AS genres
UNWIND genres AS g
MERGE (genre:Genre {name:g})
MERGE (movie)-[:HAS_GENRE]->(genre)
RETURN movie, genre;
```

Yields:

[image]

You were also referring to `rows[3]`, which is null. The csv file only has 3 columns, where the third column is accessed with `rows[2]`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. The same query format takes more than 15 minutes to make 1 million relationships (without taking significant memory or CPU time). Any advice to speed that up?

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on :Movie(MovieID) and :Genre(name). Also change it up to do `MERGE (movie:Movie {MovieID: rows[0]}) SET movie.name = rows[1]`. Also consider `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`.

Comment: Why the SET part, if I already have index defined on MovieID ?

Comment: Because then it's MERGEing on a non-indexed property.